# Half screen drill down UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to implement a drill down UITableView which occupies half of an iPhone vertical screen?

I am planning to use a `UINavigationController` since it seems to be the standard way of implementing a drill down. But a `UINavigationController` takes a `RootViewController` which usually controls a full screen.

Also if a drill down can be done on an half screen table, which is the best way of doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a UITableView and then swap it's view out when a row is selected.

See:

transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
Creates a transition animation between the specified views using the given parameters.

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:     (NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion

You'll have to either use a swipe gesture or button on that swapped view to swap back to the tableview.